# Found on Youtube "VB.NET - How to create an SQLite database within Visual Studio". When i run it from studio and it . Doesn't Work

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, visual-studio-2019

I have been failing miserably to publish another app with a database created with DB Browser: every time I publish and move to another PC it can't open the DB so I thought I'd try a different approach.

This is in module1, note I changed the sub name to myMain as it kept telling me that my project had too many Mains, don't know why as this is the only place referenced:

the link to the video I am referencing is:
https://video.search.yahoo.com/search/video?fr=mcafee&p=VB.NET+-+How+to+create+an+SQLite+database+within+Visual+Studio#id=1&vid=51539dac133b92e6a3510d3cbbcdeba8&action=click

```vb
Sub myMain()
    Dim Server As New Server()
    Server.createDataBase()
    Server.insertUsername("Paul Higginbotham")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

This is in the public server class:

```vb
'Where to install the database in this case on the desktop
Dim location As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
'Name the database
Dim fileName As String = "myDataBase.db"
'Combine the files together
Dim fullPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(location, fileName)
'Create a public connection so you don't have to keep making the connection
'everytime you are querying the database
Public connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source = {0}", fullPath)

'Create the DataBase
Public Sub createDataBase()
    If Not duplicateDataBase(fullPath) Then

        Dim createTable As String = "CREATE TABLE 'userLoginTable' (
                                'id'    INTEGER,
                                'username'  TEXT,
                                PRIMARY KEY('id' AUTOINCREMENT)
                                );"

        Using SqlConn As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(createTable, SqlConn)
            SqlConn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End If
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve the "it can't open the DB" problem? It would be better to use an [SqliteConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnectionstringbuilder) to set the DataSource - it will take care of any quotes or escapes needed for the path. Does it give an error message?

Comment: I get no errors, when I run the solution in VS.net 2019, the form opens but when I check the desktop there is no db. I have gone thru the video double checking and triple checking the code and everything matches up with the exception of the module where the Sub Main() is changed to myMain

Comment: I am also using Visual Basic not C# cause I don't know C#

Comment: If you [edit] the question to add a link to the video, someone might have time to watch it in case they can spot where it's going wrong.

Comment: @user3375228 It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video a Console Application is created. Since you got a warning about too many `Sub Main`s, I believe you were trying this code in a Windows Forms application. Nothing is calling your `myMain` sub. Try the code in a Console Application and leave the name of the sub as Sub Main. Add the class to the console application just the same. Don't forget to add the Nuget package and the Imports statement.

You could also leave it as a Windows Form and put the code from myMain into Form.Load or a Button event that you add to the Form. The class remains the same.

Comment: Thank you that was the answer and yes I was using Windows Form Application, it is now working